# Выпирающий элемент в Bottom navigation menu?

Tags: android

[image: buttom navigation menu]

Как можно реализовать bottom navigation menu c выпирающим элементов(как на картике).
Какие способы решения данной проблемы существуют?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону BottomAppBar с Fab.

Comment: То, что вам нужно - https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar. Можете поискать другие, на эту тему, которые больше подойдут Вам.

Answer (score 1):

можете использовать material design BottomAppBar 
https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/

здесь еще пример
https://devcolibri.com/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Можете еще посмотреть эту либу, ее можно гибко настроить под свои нужды. https://github.com/TalebRafiepour/BottomNavigationView